# Send Multiple Radio Button Value to Controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, radio-button, codeigniter-4

I have survey page containing multiple question and radio button for each question

```
 <table class="table">
 <form action="What should i write here" method="post">
     <?php $numbering = 1;
        foreach ($dataQuestion as $key => $value) : ?>
         <tr>
             <td width="1%"><?= $numbering++; ?></td>
             <td><?= $value->question ?>
                 <div class="form-check mt-1">
                     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="indikator[$value->id]" value="1">
                     Very Good
                     <br>
                     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="indikator[$value->id]" value="2">
                     Good
                     <br>
                     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="indikator[$value->id]" value="3">
                     Decent
                     <br>
                     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="indikator[$value->id]" value="4">
                     Bad
                     <br>
                     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="indikator[$value->id]" value="5">
                     Very Bad
                 </div>
             </td>
         </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button></td>
     </tr>
 </form>
```

I'm trying to pass selected radio button value to my controller file using `<form action="">` but every question have different answer, how to send array of all answered question to my controller via `<form action="">` ?

It seems everyone prefer to use javascript, url, and `form_radio()`. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> `<form action="What should i write here" ...>`

---

Write there the route/path meant to receive your HTTP `POST` request. I.e:

```html
<form action="/survey" method="post">
```

The state a route definition meant to receive the route in `app\Config\Routes.php`. I.e:

```php
// ...
$routes->post("/survey", "SurveyController::create");
```